# Why does my program get stuck on .add roles in python discord bot?

Tags: python, discord

```
    @bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    global warn
    if message.author == bot.user:
        return
    x = message.content
    if x.upper() == 'SPAM':
        if warn == 2:
            user = message.author
            if user is None:
                print("User not found")
            else:
                await bot.add_roles(message.author, guild.get_role("<@&1014144691744276530>"))
                warn = 0
        user = "<@&1014487310361968640>"
        await message.channel.send(user)
        warn += 1
```

The code gets stuck on: await bot.add_roles(user, "<@&1014144691744276530>")

Comment: What do you mean by "it gets stuck"? Does it crash? If so, please [edit] your question and post the [*full text* of any errors or tracebacks](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/359146). Does it simply stop responding? If so, how do you know it's at this exact spot?

Comment: It simply just stops responding. There are no error codes, but I tried to print before and after that statement and the before printed but the after didn't.